# Examples of end-to-end GoLang build pipeline

Tags: go, build

There seems to be little information around examples and best practices when building an end-to-end pipeline for a Go Lang application that can:

- Calculate next version (ala [semantic-release](https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release))
- Run all tests
- Build for the different supported platforms ((Linux, FreeBSD, Mac OS X, Windows) * (amd64, 386, arm, s390x, ppc64le))
- Tag and Release in a SCM (github | gitlab | bitbucket)
- Optionally create packages (deb, rpm, snaps, flatpaks, brew taps, Inno Setup).
- Run this integrated in (TravisCI | CircleCI | Jenkins | Bamboo | others)

Is there any documentation, example project at this regard? I've checked some of the more famous Go projects (kubernetes, hashicorp/* and others) and they all seem to leave this part outside of the project.

Comment: I covered some of those topics in https://github.com/mh-cbon/go-github-release, check also other alternatives as mentioned in below answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but you can take a look at this one [goreleaser](https://github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser).

> GoReleaser builds Go binaries for several platforms, creates a GitHub
>   release and then pushes a Homebrew formula to a repository. All that
>   wrapped in your favorite CI.

Comment: Looks pretty good indeed. Let me give it a try before accepting the answer.